# mysql data not being updated

Tags: php, html, mysql, error-handling

Whilst moving from one host to another (to hostgator) we've received many errors. We did have a news editor edit code error once we moved, but we've fixed that. Now, we have an error updating data in page editor.

It can pull/select data and says saved, but it doesn't update the data in mysql.

Hosting error? was working before.

```
<a href="pageeditor.php?page=events">&raquo;Events Page</a>
<a href="pageeditor.php?page=app">&raquo;Jobs Page</a>
<a href="pageeditor.php?page=maintenance">&raquo;Maintenance Page</a>
<a href="pageeditor.php?page=staff">&raquo;Staff Page</a>
```

Thank you,

Comment: where is your connection? it seems that there is no connection present or connection file included

Comment: I do Usman, it's up the top of the page. Also, there is `$page = clean($_GET[page]);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your previous host had autocommit=on, meaning you do not have to COMMIT.
Try a COMMIT statement at the end of each data update to actually save the data

```
   echo("The CMS for the credits page has been updated!");
```

is just the php saying what you want it to say, it did not actually go into the database and check...

Answer (score 0):

use

```
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else 
{
echo("maintenance page updated");
}
```

to identify that your query is working fine or not

Comment: RETURNS `Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/****/public_html/pageeditor.php on line 93
Error:`

Comment: please update your connection code. you have to change $con & $sql according to your connection and query

Comment: give a try to if(!mysql_query("update usr_cms set cont6 = '$cont6' where page = 6"))

Comment: I tried that way and it only works for the first page, which is maintenance. I tried them on the rest and again it won't update.